# C++: handling errors, can't understand my mistake

Tags: c++

1.Check the user input. If the input does not match three floating-point numbers, output an error message and do not start the calculation.
2.Check whether a==0. If so, throw a runtime_error and catch it in main, printing a message saying that a must not be 0.

The error messages should look like this:

An error occured: Malformed user input

An error occurred: a must not be zero

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

vector<double> solutionFinal (double a, double b, double c){


    double s1, s2, discriminant;

    discriminant = b*b - 4*a*c;

    if (discriminant > 0){
        s1 = (-b + sqrt(discriminant)) / (2*a);
        s2 = (-b - sqrt(discriminant)) / (2*a);
        cout << "There are 2 solutions." << endl;
        cout << "The solutions are: " << s1 << " and  " << s2;
        return {s1, s2};
    }

    else if (discriminant == 0) {
        cout << "There is 1 solution." << endl;
        s1 = (-b + sqrt(discriminant)) / (2*a);
        cout << "The solution is: " << s1;
        return {s1};
    }

    else {
        cout << "There is no solution."  << endl;
        return {};
    }
}
int main (){


    double a, b, c;
    cout << "Please enter the values of a, b, and c respectively:" << endl;


    try{
        if (!(cin >> a >> b >> c)) {
        throw runtime_error("An error occured: Malformed user input");
    }

        if (a == 0) {
        throw runtime_error("An erorr occured: a must not be zero");
        }

    }

    auto result = solutionFinal(a, b, c);
    for (auto scalar : result){
    }
    catch (runtime_error& excpt) {
      cout << excpt.what();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what is your question? What is happening, what did you *expect* to happen instead?

Comment: If your issue is that you can't compile, you need to move the code that is between the `try` and `catch` blocks inside the `try` block, if not we need a [mcve]

Comment: According to the instructions, point 1 should not throw an exception, just print a message and quit. The intent of point 2 is that `solutionFinal` should throw the exception, which you catch in `main`. (Throwing and catching in the same function is usually just a way of pretending that you're avoiding `goto`.) You should also move the output from `solutionFinal` to `main`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is malformed, your braces don't add up. I prefer another brace style because I think it's easier to see that way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

vector<double> solutionFinal (double a, double b, double c)
{    
    double s1, s2, discriminant;

    discriminant = b*b - 4*a*c;

    if (discriminant > 0)
    {
        s1 = (-b + sqrt(discriminant)) / (2*a);
        s2 = (-b - sqrt(discriminant)) / (2*a);
        cout << "There are 2 solutions." << endl;
        cout << "The solutions are: " << s1 << " and  " << s2;
        return {s1, s2};
    }
    else if (discriminant == 0) 
    {
        cout << "There is 1 solution." << endl;
        s1 = (-b + sqrt(discriminant)) / (2*a);
        cout << "The solution is: " << s1;
        return {s1};
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "There is no solution."  << endl;
        return {};
    }
}

int main ()
{
    double a, b, c;

    cout << "Please enter the values of a, b, and c respectively:" << endl;

    try
    {
        if (!(cin >> a >> b >> c)) 
        {
            throw runtime_error("An error occured: Malformed user input");
        }

        if (a == 0) 
        {
            throw runtime_error("An erorr occured: a must not be zero");
        }

        // this block was outside the try, between the try and the catch.
        // it MUST be inside the try block like this
        auto result = solutionFinal(a, b, c);
        for (auto scalar : result)
        {
        }
    }
    catch (runtime_error& excpt) 
    {
        cout << excpt.what();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply.